# Getting row right after insert returns no result

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am running unit tests and when I try to insert data in the database and getting it right after, I don't get anything (I have tried with `DataAdapter` and `DataReader`).

However when I put a 3 seconds sleep (even with 1 second it doesn't work...) between the insert and the select I get the result.

In SQL Server Profiler I can see the execution, the insert is well done and is completed about 10 miliseconds before the select begins.

I can't find out where this comes

The code looks like this :
Insert method

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlTemplate);
command.Parameters.Add(Sql4oConstants.Sql4oIdParameterName, SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = id;
command.Parameters.Add(Sql4oConstants.Sql4oTimestampParamterName, SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

command.CommandTimeout = dataSourceDescription.CommandTimeout;
DatabaseManager.ExecuteNonQuery(dataSourceDescription.ConnectionString, command);
```

Get method

```
public static void Fill(string connectionString, DataTable table, SqlCommand command)
    {
        try
        {
            LogStorageWriter.WriteLogEntry(log, EStorageLevelLog.Debug, string.Format("Execute query: {0}", command.CommandText));

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                command.Connection = conn;
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(table);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            LogStorageWriter.WriteLogEntry(log, EStorageLevelLog.Error, string.Format("Exception : {0}", e.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can append the `SELECT ...` to the `INSERT` in the sql. Then you can do both in one command.

Comment: In your scenario, what's the value of `sqlTemplate` in the first method? What's the value of `command` in the second method?

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. I'll post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

In fact, it was because my request used a CONTAINS. I then discovered that using a CONTAINS calls the SQL Server Indexer to fetch data. But the engine does not index data instantly. 
That's why I had to wait 2 or 3 seconds to get my data back.